# SpecifiedPickupDirectory will not create files until viewed by a user on the server

Tags: asp.net, iis, smtp

I'm using a "trick" (nicely described [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/05/27/asp-net-using-pickup-directory-for-outgoing-e-mails.aspx)) to store my emails on the application server during testing.

My config file looks like this:

```
<system.net>  
    <mailSettings>    
        <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" from="no-reply@here.com">      
            <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="E:\EmailStore" />    
        </smtp>  
    </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

The directory exists and it has no rights issues.

Here is the problem.  The files won't be created until I navigate to the folder on the server.  Then all of a sudden **bang** all the files are poping into the directory.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

I've noticed there is another choice - `PickupDirectoryFromIis` -- but I'm unclear when I should use `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` and when I should use `PickupDirectoryFromIis`.

What is the difference between `SpecifiedPickupDirectory` and `PickupDirectoryFromIis`? When should I use one over the other?  Is this the cause of the files not appearing till I navigate?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was a project that was migrated from ASP.NET 3.5 to ASP.NET 4.0

It seems that `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient` now implements `IDisposable`.  Change the code to use the following pattern seems to have solved the problem.

Best guess as to cause was the GC was not being called and the file buffer was not being flushed.

```
using (System.Net.Mail.MailMessage email = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage())
{
   using (System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient smtp = new System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient())
   {
      // code
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That is strange. We use SpecifiedPickupDirectory for our test fixtures as well, to unit test email sending / receiving features. However, we keep the directory on the C:\ drive. Is the E:\ drive mapped to a network drive? Or is it local? Have you tried changing it to a location on C:\? Do you have the same problem?

Comment: E:\ is local to the machine.  (The whole machine is virtual, but that should not matter.)  The directory is set up as a shared drive (so the QA team can look at the emails.)

Answer (score 0):

I tried to write (and get from the web too) the difference between the methods: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpdeliverymethod.aspx

```
Network
```

The e-mail is sent through a direct connection to the specified SMTP server.

```
SpecifiedPickupDirectory
```

Indicates that directory specified by `PickupDirectoryLocation` will be used as the SMTP pickup directory. **If the SMTP client is unable to write to the pickup directory location an I/O exception is thrown by Send**. The directory will not be created if it does not exist. **The credentials of the currently running thread or process will be used to access the directory**.
This is useful when you have an external custom program that picks up e-mails from that folder and processes them

```
PickupDirectoryFromIis
```

The e-mail message is prepared and the EML file is saved into the default directory from which IIS picks up queued e-mails to send. By default this is:\Inetpub\mailroot\Queue.

However, when using the second and third delivery methods, your web application cannot be notified of any errors that may occur during transmission of the message, and it will be up to IIS (or another mail agent that might be used) to handle them. In general, the PickupDirectoryFromIis method is the preferred one, unless your ASP.NET application is not given the right to write to IIS mail folders (check with your web hosting provider service if you don’t use your own servers).
SO, can be a permission issue?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, some notes: I have full control over the server and created the directory with full rights for the service account and all local administrators and shared the directory with read rights to everyone on the domain.  The send function gets no errors.  In fact the file does get saved just fine except it happens later when I log onto the server locally and navigate to the directory.

Comment: I'm looking for your problem, but is really strange! Virtual server and IIS 7 right? When you log onto the server and go to the path, you walk by \\server-name\share\EmailStore? I hope, that server log can tell you something; have you tried to change E:\EmailStore to \\server-name\share\EmailStore in the web.config?

Comment: No, I have to log into the server so I use the "Computer" browser (from the start tab) to navigate to `E:\EmailStore`.  (When users external to the server look at `\\servername\EmailStore` they don't see the files.

Comment: Nope.  No errors reported anywhere.  If so I would have mentioned that in the question.